# How to get the object name of "this" in either javascript or/and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm reading someone else plugin code to gain a better understanding because of poor documentation. I'm seeing a lot of "this" objects and need to know the name of its object that it refers to for the "this" object? I'm not sure if "this" object is in jquery or javascriopt..... I hope this is a value question because I have no starting point code in obtaining "this" object name.. Also not knowing if "this" object was created as a literal object or constructor object

Comment: Perhaps this page will be of use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
this.nodeName
this.tagName
```

or

```
$(this).prop("tagName")
$(this).prop("nodeName")
```

Comment: Or if it's a DOM then you'll need to access the element array, `if(this[0]) elemName = this[0].nodeName;`

Answer (score 1):

`this` in a method refers to whatever object the method was called from.
So, for example take the following code block:

```
var x = {};
x.myFunc = new function(){this.foo = 1;}
x.myFunc();
alert(x.foo);
```

After this, alert will run and display `1`

This is the most common way of getting a `this`. You can also use the [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method to manually set an object as `this` for the purposes of running that method.

If there's no scope for `this` to come from (i.e. it's not called on an object) `this` will refer to with `window` element.